# Comments or annotations in Gmail messages

Tags: gmail

How can I use Gmail to put some comments/notes on the emails that are only visible to me?

For instance, a user asks me for something I could make a note like "ask Mkt dpt of this and send ASAP. If no response is given until Thursday, ask again!"

How do I set this up in Gmail? Is there any free extension?

Comment: Doesn't creating a draft of the email, and not sending it, will be enought?

Comment: not really @woliveirajr

Comment: I don't have the rep yet to leave a proper reply. But try [Front](frontapp.com). It's an e-mail client that lets you share e-mail: it works with Gmail, and it lets you comment or leave notes on any e-mail you send or receive (visible only to you and/or your team.) It works in the browser or as a dedicated app. P.S.: it's not free.

Comment: I use [gmail notes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-notes/elogffplkfhmdkmkiganmbghjhfdfpfm/related) and I am very happy with this plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest [Active Inbox](http://www.activeinboxhq.com), a Firefox Addon for Gmail. The free version allows to organize email using the GTD methodology, but the Plus version (which is paid) has other features such as notes and deadlines in the emails.

Comment: WOW! It is awesome! The catch is the price... I think it is a little bit expensive (and takes to much space on screen...)

Answer (score 3):

what about "More", "Add to Tasks" in GMail? It seems you are giving yourself a **task** here where you say "if no response until Thursday, ask again."

https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106237&ctx=mail

You could also consider a set of **labels** in gmail.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=118708#0

Comment: Good answer! I was going to mention *Labels* too, first thing that came to mind! Active Inbox might be overkill (or maybe not, but it isn't free). Labels is very easy to use, does exactly what you need, and it might be possible to sync with your Google Calendar, though I'm less certain of the latter.

Comment: The problem of tasks is that it doesn't get associated with a particular email...

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro but labels do. I don't think what you want exists, exactly, so you'll need to experiment and see what is acceptable.

Comment: @JeffAtwood But with labels I can't add notes to an email :( ActiveInbox is the best (and only) that I've seen so far..

Answer (score 2):

You can always send a reply to yourself and it will be part of the conversation. For more complex stuff there are extensions available for Google apps for Business in the Google Apps market.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Boomerang for Gmail](http://www.boomeranggmail.com). Works with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Boomerang will return the email from Archive to Inbox at specified time and attach a [note](http://baydin.com/blog/2011/10/boomerang-brings-recurring-emails-notes-to-gmail/) to the conversation thread.
The note feature is not free, but with this app you get a clear screen and a clean inbox :)